# How to get the count of Server where we have Error equal to yes?

Tags: awk

```
cat file.txt
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : no
[Server]  : fgh
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : def
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
```

> expected output : Wherver we have yes in Error line we have to add the
>   value of that server from 2nd line and then count those value which
>   contain yes for Error line.

```
abc 4
def 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If output order does't matter then

```
awk 'n && /^\[Server\]/{n=!(a[$3]++);next}!n{n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes"}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '                               # Call awk
     n && /^\[Server\]/{            # if n is true and line starts with Server
              n=!(a[$3]++);         # increment the value of array a 
                                    # where index being $3 ( column3 )
                                    # negate the value of expression return false
                                    # and hence set variable n false or 0
                                    # in short instead of n=0 for resetting variable n
                                    # I used n!=(a[$3]++),
                                    # even parenthesis "()" not required, kept
                                    # for better reading

              next                  # stop processing go to next line
     }
    !n{                             # if n is false or 0, negate of value becomes true and do the following
        n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes" # if  line starts with ERROR 
                                    # and column3 equal to yes then
                                    # set variable n with boolean state
                                    # if condition evaluates true then n will be 1 or true
                                    # else n will be 0 or false
    }
    END{                            # loop through array and print array
                                    # index and array value
         for(i in a)
            print i,a[i]
    }
    ' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file 
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : no
[Server]  : fgh
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : def
[Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes
[Server]  : abc
[Status]  : completed;
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'n && /^\[Server\]/{n=!(a[$3]++);next}!n{n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes"}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
def 1
abc 4
```

**--EDIT-- with new input given on comment**

**New-Input**

```
$ cat newfile
[ERROR] : yes 
[Status] : completed; 
[Server] : abc 
[ERROR] : yes 
[Status] : completed; 
[Server] : abc 
[ERROR] : yes 
[Status] : completed; 
[Server] : abc 
[ERROR] : no 
[Status] : completed; 
[Server] : fgh
```

**New-Output**

```
$ awk 'n && /^\[Server\]/{n=!(a[$3]++);next}!n{n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes"}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' newfile
abc 3
```

Comment: can you please explain - how this n{a[$3]++} is checking for Server line?

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: `n` will be true, as and when its finds that line which starts with `ERROR` and third col is `yes`, if `n` is true meaning previous line was error, so `n{a[$3]++}` = `true{a[server_name]++}`, in short if last line was error, then increment array a where index being server name, value will be summed each time

Comment: Understood - if ERROR line contain yes then variable n become true and upon passing it to array a[$3]++(keep on adding if n is true )
It will work fine when server is next to Error line. If we need to test it for different condition when server line is followed by status line, in that case how we can modify this command - (sample input below )

`[ERROR]   : yes
[Status]  : completed;
[Server]  : abc
[ERROR]   : yes
[Status]  : completed;
[Server]  : abc
[ERROR]   : yes
[Status]  : completed;
[Server]  : abc
[ERROR]   : no
[Status]  : completed;
[Server]  : fgh`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR:  I modified my post, which works with both input, you may try now

Comment: Thanks for your response to new test case but can you please explain this part for me - 

`n && /^\[Server\]/{n=!(a[$3]++);next}!n{n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes"}`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: added explanation also on top, I think you didn't see, if you still have any doubt, feel free to ask

Comment: I have seen that explanation but still I have one doubt - 

`[ERROR]   : yes             ##### {n=/^\[ERROR\]/ && $3=="yes"} means n = true or 1
[Status]  : completed;
[Server]  : abc             ##### n && /^\[Server\]/{n=!(a[$3]++);next} means ( 1 && 1 {1=!a[$3]++})`

How this part is working ?

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR when line starts with `[Status] : completed;`  nothing will happen, because string SERVER not found and `n` is already true . `!n` is zero, when line starts with `[Server] : abc #####`  `n` will reset back to `zero`, because of `!` operator, array `a` will increment each time for corresponding server name as index,  array value will be non zero always so negate of any nonzero value will be zero. first time when it sees server `abc` `a[abc]++` will be 1, so negate of it is zero, second time when awk sees server `abc` `a[abc]++` will be `2`, so negate of it is zero and so on

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
    awk -F: '$1~/^\[ERROR]/ && $2~/yes/ { getline; a[$2]++ } END { for (x in a) { print x,a[x] }  }' file.txt

abc 4
def 1
```

Comment: `getline` isn't appropriate for this due to the caveats/complications it brings with it, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: from the original question, I didn't get too much info. He had an input and expected output so I tried my best.

Comment: I completely understand but getline is something you use in a few very limited situations for a very specific purpose, it's not something you use otherwise. If this were C you'd probably have the right approach but this is AWK so a different paradigm and different idioms.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '($1=="[Server]") && (err=="yes"){cnt[$NF]++} {err=$NF} END{for (srvr in cnt) print srvr, cnt[srvr]}' file
def 1
abc 4
```

Comment: One doubt - is there any specific reason to add "+0" at the end?

Comment: Not in this particular case (so I'll remove it) since every element of `cnt[]` has a value but if, for example we were looping through an array of **all** server names and only some had hit the `cnt[$NF]++` statement then doing +0 ensures that **every** output is a digit. Try `awk -v OFS=':' 'BEGIN{cnt["a"]; cnt["b"]++; for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i], cnt[i]+0}'` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with trick -

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%3==0?RS:FS)}1' file.txt > file2.txt
OR
awk '{ORS=(/;/?RS:FS)}1' file.txt > file2.txt

cat file2.txt 
[ERROR]   : yes [Server]  : abc [Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes [Server]  : abc [Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes [Server]  : abc [Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : no [Server]  : fgh [Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes [Server]  : def [Status]  : completed;
[ERROR]   : yes [Server]  : abc [Status]  : completed;


awk '{if($3 == "yes") a[$6]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file2.txt 
def 1
abc 4
```